# I am getting a syntax error from psycopg2. It works if i use sqlite3

Tags: python, postgresql

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Sublime Text 3\project\webscrabe\temp.py", line 30, in <module>
    insert('hello', 20, 'poepen')
  File "E:\Sublime Text 3\project\webscrabe\temp.py", line 28, in insert
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Gpus(Name, Price, Deliverytime) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",(x, y, z))
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: INSERT INTO Gpus(Name, Price, Deliverytime) VALUES(?, ?, ?)
                                                            ^

[Finished in 1.3s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "E:\Sublime Text 3\project\webscrabe\temp.py"]
[dir: E:\Sublime Text 3\project\webscrabe]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\David\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;E:\Python\Scripts\;E:\Python\;C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;E:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin;C:\Users\David\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;C:\Users\David\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin]
```

Code:
    ```

````
import psycopg2
# import sqlite3
# conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

DB_NAME = "xcsvohqb"
DB_USER = "xcsvohqb"
DB_PASS = ""
DB_HOST = "ruby.db.elephantsql.com"
DB_PORT = "5432"

conn = psycopg2.connect(database=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS,host=DB_HOST,port=DB_PORT)

c = conn.cursor()

#c.execute("""
#CREATE TABLE Gpus
#(
#Name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
#Price INT NOT NULL,
#Deliverytime TEXT NOT NULL

#)

#   """) 
#conn.commit()

def insert(name, price, deliverytime):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Gpus(Name, Price, Deliverytime) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",(x, y, z))
    conn.commit()
insert('test', 20, 'test')


def get_posts():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Gpus")
    print(c.fetchall())

get_posts()

```
````

I am using postgreSQL and pgadmin 4.
If i use sqlite3 it works fine. How do i fix this error?
This is my first time asking a question, i'm sorry if i formatted something incorrect

Comment: psycopg2 is using `%s` as placeholder.